# Facebook Application request

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to give **Application request** to the list of user from my android application.

The main thing is **"The App request must not go to wall , it must go to user's inbox or App request list"**

is there any way using graph api or facebook api.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to embed the [Facebook Requests dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/) into a web view.  There isn't a graph api method for sending app invites.

Comment: thanks dude .. just i removed m.facebook.com to facebook.com in that URL it worked..

Answer (score 2):

Now they have added the Requests dialog api for android too. Check out the facebook android sdk documentation! https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/build/

Answer (score 0):

You must create a Dialog using WebDialog.RequestsDialogBuilder, also the most important thing is to set the method for apprequests:

```
Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
params.putString("method", "apprequests");
WebDialog.RequestsDialogBuilder req = new WebDialog.RequestsDialogBuilder(this, mSession, parameters);
req.setMessage("Your message");
req.setTitle("Title for the web dialog");
req.build().show();
```

You can find more explanations [here](http://spinettaro.blogspot.it/2013/01/how-to-send-facebook-app-request.html)